# Access keys of pandas dataframe when using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, pandas-groupby

I have the following database:

[image]

And I would like to know how many times a combination of BirthDate and Zipcode is repeated throughout the data table:

[image]

Now, my question is: How can I access the keys of this output? For instance, how can I get Birthdate=2000101 ZipCode=8002, for i = 0?

The problem is this is a 'Series' object, so I'm not able to use `.columns`, `.loc` or `.query` here.

[image]

Comment: if `s = df.groupby(['birthdate', 'zipcode']).size()`

Comment: @jezrael i can't use query here

Comment: so need `s.loc[(2000101, 8002)]` ?